# how to pass variable from page to partial

Tags: octobercms, october-partial

HI I want to pass a value from my page and grab it on partial,for example bellow is example
Main layout

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   .....
  </head>
  <body>
    {% partial 'a_partial' %}
  </body>
</html>
```

And my partial

```
<h1>{{ value-from-page}}</h1>
```

and on page I tried like bellow

```
function onRender()
{
    $this['value-from-page'] = "A string";
}
==
```

This way I am getting output on partial '0',I tried dump() on partial and its showing 'value-from-page' and its value. What is wrong am I doing?

Comment: please check this document: https://octobercms.com/docs/cms/partials#partial-variables, it has clear definition how to pass variable to partials

Comment: if you face any issue please update question we are happy to help

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass your variables this way:

```
{% partial 'a_partial' var1='var 1 content' var2='var 2 content' %}
```